# Error Code: 1264. Out of range value for column

Tags: mysql, insert, varchar

I'm trying to get my code to work and just from the first line I'm inserting I get an error. I've already changed the value of the phone number's to varchar, but this error still remains.

This is my code:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `mydb` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Customer` (
`Customer_ID` INT NOT NULL,
`Customer_F_Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`Customer_L_Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`Customer_Address` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`Customer_DOB` DATE NOT NULL,
`Customer_H_Phone` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`Customer_W_Phone` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`Customer_Type` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`Customer_Sponsor_ID` INT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Customer_ID`),
INDEX `fk_Customer_Customer1_idx` (`Customer_Sponsor_ID` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_Customer_Customer1`
FOREIGN KEY (`Customer_Sponsor_ID`)
REFERENCES `mydb`.`Customer` (`Customer_ID`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;



INSERT INTO `Customer` (`Customer_ID`, `Customer_F_Name`, `Customer_L_Name`, 
`Customer_Address`, `Customer_DOB`, `Customer_H_Phone`, `Customer_W_Phone`, 
`Customer_Type`, `Customer_Sponsor_ID`) VALUES 
(1, 'Nicole', 'Gilbert', '8295 Golden Leaf Alley', 
'1992-03-28', '5744813109', '1646648129', 'Student', NULL);
```

And then when I just insert the first line of data this is the error I get:

```
INSERT INTO `Customer` (`Customer_ID`, `Customer_F_Name`,   `Customer_L_Name`, 
`Customer_Address`, `Customer_DOB`, `Customer_H_Phone`, `Customer_W_Phone`, 
`Customer_Type`, `Customer_Sponsor_ID`) VALUES 
(1, 'Nicole', 'Gilbert', '8295 Golden Leaf Alley', 
 '1992-03-28', '5744813109', '1646648129', 'Student', NULL) 
Error Code: 1264. Out of range value for column 
'Customer_H_Phone' at row 1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Since your table exists it will not be re-created.  Have you tried explicitly dropping it?

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you!